# What is the best approach to storing an image to a database if there are multiple users and they all have multiple entries?

Tags: mysql, database

I am learning about storing images to database. So, from what I gather, you store links or urls to the images and the string value of the images get stored while the actual images get stored in a folder.
My app will have a profile for each user logged in. Each user can create entries, let's say vehicles. So each user can have many vehicles, and for simplicity in this example, a vehicle may only have one image.
So when storing the images, do the images all get stored in one directory with each image named uniquely after the username for example `johnsmith1.jpg`, `johnsmith2.jpg`? Or does each user get a folder each with their name on the folder to identify the folder uniquely and then store the images in that folder? Or if a vehicle can have multiple images, does each vehicle get a folder?
I am confused because I do not know if having one folder and having all images in there is a good idea and a good practice.

Comment: Give any image a UUID to prevent any conflicts, all else is optional.

Comment: @luk2302 so its okay to dump them all in the same folder as long as they have a UUID? I just wondered if it would be more organized and faster loading if there were separate folders. I mean wouldnt it enhance performance if the query only had to look at one a folder with less images instead of one folder with all images?